# Undocumented useful commands in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

```
\tikzstyle{...}=[...]
```

This command seems to be extremely useful since it allows to re-use the same style in multiple TikZ pictures.

Is is used in a few places in TikZ manual (pgfmanual.pdf), but why it is not defined or described?

What are the other useful commands not described in TikZ manual?

Comment: The documented command to define styles is \tikzset (see Section 11.4 of the version 2.00 manual). As a general warning: If possible never use undocumented commands. They might be dropped in later releases.

Comment: Related question: [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)

Answer (score 11):

The command `\tikzstyle` is not well documented because the author would like to encourage users to set styles locally instead. Styles should be declared

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[..., certain style/.style={...}, ...]
...
\en{tikzpicture}
```

This way the style belongs to that picture.

Perhaps read this message of the author Till Tantau: [Keeping the tikzstyle command](http://osdir.com/ml/tex.pgf.user/2007-08/msg00004.html).

Comment: Till's message is encouraging do-repeat-yourself approach, which is strange.

Comment: What's the difference between tikzstyle and tikzset?

Comment: @Łukasz First `\tikzset`is recommended by T Tantau, and then I think `\tikzset` is quicker than `\tikzstyle` because for compatibility `\tikzstyle` now uses `pgfkeys` or `\tikzset` is defined by `\def\tikzset{\pgfqkeys{/tikz}} `. Tantau writes also `\pgfqkeys` is quicker.

Comment: If `\tikzstyle` is used inside the environment `tikzpicture`, it seems to be local to this environment,no ? and it's the same for `tikzset` but I agree with you with the fact that T Tantau recommends to define the styles locally.

Comment: @ŁukaszLew: Just a very late reaction to your complaint.  It's possible to write `\tikzset{some style/.style = ...}` anywhere in the document to globally create a style; the style doesn't have to be constructed in each individual picture.  So repetition is not necessary.

Answer (score 8):

From the [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) manual you can find that there is a macro called `\pgfdeclareimage` (Section 13, *Graphics*). This can be used to load a graphics file with a reusable name, to be applied using `\pgfuseimage`. This is obviously best for cases where the image is repeated in the output file (it only needs to be included once in the PDF, saving on file size). `\pgfdeclareimage`  takes an optional argument for graphics settings, in the same way as `\includegraphics`.

Comment: oops, I just edited my answer as requested by Łukasz ... I will roll back my edit.

Comment: I guess we must both have added to this at almost the same time, so the 'an answer has been posted' thing did not pop up. I'm guessing that one (or as here a few related) macro per answer makes most sense.

Comment: Of course, that's why I rolled back. I edited just to avoid to post multiple answers myself. Back ontopic, here's a link to the reference of those commands from the 1.01 manual: http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/contrib/tex-contrib/beamer/pgf-1.01/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-tex4ht/en/pgfmanualse27.html

Comment: I notice that it basically says 'most LaTeX users of Tikz should ignore this command', to paraphrase :-)

Comment: So, there's a reason why the current manual keeps those commands 'secret'.