# Tikz: using external images as building blocks.

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I would like to create a custom vector drawing in Inkscape and then use it many times in many tikz pictures.

Is it possible?
Should I use PDF or SVG or other output from Inkscape?
How to use external vector image in Tikz node?
How to define anchors / dimensions(bounding box)?

Comment: Some of your questions are answered in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/how-to-include-svg-diagrams-in-latex

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**PGF tools for working with external images:**

- use `\pgfdeclareimage` to make your external image known to pgf/TikZ
- use `\pgfuseimage{name}` to include the image into your document
- encapsulate the image by `\pgfbox` to be able to use it within a node

An advantage of this way is that each image will be included just once in a pdf document and may be reused several times, thus saving space.

Follow general recommendations about including pictures: prefer vector format like pdf.

**Code example:**

This small example builds a tree with nodes using external images. I've simple taken images from our site for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfdeclareimage{gold}{gold}
\pgfdeclareimage{silver}{silver}
\pgfdeclareimage{bronze}{bronze}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=12em]
  \node {\pgfbox[center,bottom]{\pgfuseimage{gold}}}
    child {node {\pgfbox[center,top]{\pgfuseimage{silver}}}}
    child {node {\pgfbox[center,top]{\pgfuseimage{bronze}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: tree with images as nodes]

**Further explanation of the pgf commands:**

- `\pgfdeclareimage[options]{image name}{file name}` declares an image without printing it. It understands `key=value` options like height, width, page, interpolate and mask. The usual formats are supported and their extensions would automatically be tried.
- `\pgfuseimage{image name}` simply outputs that image.
- `\pgfbox[horizontal alignment,vertical alignment]{content}` outputs the content aligned left, center or right respectively top, center, bottom or base.

Detailed syntax, options and examples could be found in the pgf user guide.

**The normal LaTeX approach:**

You could simply use `\includegraphics`, use it within `\pgftext`. The example modified in this sense:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=12em]
  \node[anchor=south] {\pgftext{\includegraphics{gold}}}
    child {node[anchor=north] {\pgftext{\includegraphics{silver}}}}
    child {node[anchor=north] {\pgftext{\includegraphics{bronze}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Choosing the right way:**

Using `\includegraphics` instead of pgf commands is recommended [here](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/contrib/tex-contrib/beamer/pgf-1.01/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-tex4ht/en/pgfmanualse27.html) because `\includegraphics` is a better implementation. The pgf way may be preferred if the document size matters and graphics are multiply used or if masking is desired.

Comment: How do you know about pgfdecareimage? It is not to be found in pgfmanual.pdf. Can you answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1900/undocumented-useful-commands-in-tikz ?

Comment: Can I include PDF or SVG?

Comment: As far as I know PDF, JPEG, PNG, EPS and PS but not SVG.

Comment: `\pgfdeclareimage` is mentioned in the `beamer` manual: as Till Tantau wrote both `pgf` and `beamer` I guess he just assumed it was covered. I've added an answer to the other question about this.

Comment: The community here is amazing. You make this site a gold mine.
Thanks to all.

Comment: Could you provide an example where including the same image multiple times give a significantly larger output if done with graphicx and \includegraphics compared to pgf and \pgf{declare,use}image? If I do a simple experiment with a \loop <insert graphics> \repeat the resulting pdf-file is slightly *smaller* if I use \includegraphics. My small test was done with pdflatex-1.40.10.

Comment: Perhaps pdf compression removes that difference. I suggest this issue could be discussed in a separate question, thus further user could test and report.

Comment: I have posted a question about this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2163/resulting-document-size-when-including-a-graphics-file-multiple-times-pgf-vs-g

Comment: @Stefan: The image above was accidently lost by the provider. See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/the-image-you-are-requesting-does-not-exist-or-is-no-longer-available/1411#1411

Comment: @Stefan: Maybe it's worth re-producing the image?

Comment: @HendrikVogt: thank you and xport, I re-uploaded the image.

Comment: According to Till Tantau the *only* advantage of `\pgfdeclareimage` over `\includegraphics` is the masking; apparently `\includegraphics` is even slightly better wrt. duplicate elimination: _Like `\pgfdeclareimage`, `\includegraphics` also includes an image only once in a .pdf file, even if it used several times (as a matter of fact, the graphics package is even a bit smarter about this than pgf). However, currently only pgf offers the ability to include images that are partly transparent._ [beameruserguide.pdf, p132]

Comment: @Daniel In `pgf` manual p647, there is also a rough argument about why and how he thinks it is better.

Comment: egreg, could you please explain why one have to use `\pgfbox`/`\pgftext` I’m using `\includegraphics` directly as node content and it works fine, I guess …

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea if you swap the order of the approaches in your answer. `\includegraphics` is almost always preferred, and definitely easier to use. Having the answer in the current order has the potential to confuse people who are just looking for a straightforward way to include an image in TikZ.