# Bounding box of pictures used in TikZ/PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, captions

I am creating TikZ pictures using some external images in the following manner:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering\small
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
        \pgfdeclareimage[width=2cm]{moon}{moon.png}
        \node (moonn) at (O) {\pgfbox[center,center]{\pgfuseimage{moon}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{This is a long caption. As you can see it interferes with the Moon!}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that there does not seem to be a bounding box around the image, and it thus interferes with the caption:

[image: Caption interference]

How can I solve this problem? Am I using wrong code?

---

*Appendix*

Used image:

[image: The Moon]

Comment: You can (and indeed usually should) just use the normal `\includegraphics` command to insert an image in a node: `\node (moon) at (O) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{moon}};` works. Do you have a particular reason for using `\pgfdeclareimage`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Jake. Maybe I misread, but I understood from the question below that I have to "encapsulate the image by \pgfbox to be able to use it within a node". Source:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2152/tikz-using-external-images-as-building-blocks

Comment: There really is no reason to go that way. Check the comments under the answer, especially [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2152/tikz-using-external-images-as-building-blocks#comment70409_2153]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting the image reference into `\pgfbox[center,center]{...}` is the culprit. It creates a zero-size box with its content centred.

Just say:

```
\node (moon) at (O) {\pgfuseimage{moon}};
```