# Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?

Tags: tikz-pgf, best-practices, tikz-styles, pgfkeys

The PGF/TikZ manual states in section 12.4 *Using Graphic Options*, page 120 (v2.10), that TikZ styles can be set using:

```
\tikzset{my style/.style={<tikz options>},...}
```

However, in several places in the same manual the otherwise undocumented macro `\tikzstyle` is used for settings styles:

```
\tikzstyle{my style}=[<tikz options>]
```

I also have seen this usage in several online code examples.

Why are there two ways to set TikZ styles and which one should be used for new code?

<sub>Note: I actually know the answer but think that such a question with good answers would be beneficial for other users.</sub>

Comment: I prefer `\tikzset` as it looks like the options that would be passed to a command

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Someone on pgf-users list writes to T Tantau :

> I suggest keeping the old syntax,
>       `\tikzstyle{my style}=[some options,...]` since it is much easier to read and understand. The new syntax would be for the more "advanced"
>   users and library writers.

Answer of Till Tantau :

> I'm a bit undecided on this.
>
> First, for compatibility reasons `\tikzstyle` will be around indefinitely, so the real question is what will be better for new code.
>
> The reason I'm trying to kick out the `\tikzstyle` is that I would like to encourage people to keep style settings as local as possible. So, normally, style definitions should be given at the beginning of a picture as in
>
> ```
> \begin{tikzpicture}
> [some options,
> first style/.style={blah},
> second style/.style={blub}]    ...
> \end{tikzpicture}
> ```
>
> Then, if the `tikzpicture` is moved/copied/whatever, the styles are moved around with it. Furthermore, styles given as options always apply to the whole scope and end with it automatically.
>
> However, I'm also not quite sure whether this argument is all that convincing. Global styles still have to be set globally using
>
> ```
>  \tikzset anyway...
> ```
>
> I have started to change the whole documentation code to the new   system and it does not seem to change the readability much.

Now I think if you find some `\tikzstyle`  in several places in the manual It's because it's not very important in these cases and perhaps the author forgot to correct the very big document.

Remarks:

1. The full answer can be found online at http://osdir.com/ml/tex.pgf.user/2007-08/msg00004.html
2. The answer continued:

   > Anyway, you can now say things like
   >
   > ```
   > \tikzstyle{my style}=[draw=#1,fill=#1!20]
   > ```
   >
   > and I have actually extended the syntax of `\tikzstyle` so that one can also provide a default argument as in
   >
   > ```
   > \tikzstyle{my style}[red]=[draw=#1,fill=#1!20]
   > ```

   I never try this because I don't use `\tikzstyle`.
3. For pgfplots, see page 8 of the [pgfplots manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf) [revision 1.8]:

   > Starting with `pgfplots` 1.1, `\tikzstyle` should *no longer be used* to set `pgfplots` options.
   >
   > Although `\tikzstyle` is still supported for some older `pgfplotsoptions`, you should replace any occurance of  `\tikzstyle` with `\pgfplotsset{style name/.style={key-value-list}}` or the
   >   associated `/.append style` variant.

   Then, on page 280:

   > Please note that it is not possible to use the TikZ-command `\tikzstyle{stylename}=[]`. This  was possible in a previous version and is still supported for backwards compatibility. But in some cases, it may not work as expected.

Comment: This answer would benefit if you could add a short summary on the top.

Comment: Yes you are right, I will make it when I have a little time (actually I write  some programming notes about TikZ  and it will be useful to add some notes about styles)

Comment: @AlainMatthes: Are your programming notes about TikZ publicly available? If so where? Thanks.

Comment: `\tikzstyle{red_circle} = [draw, circle, fill=red!20]`
  
`\tikzset{red_circle/.style = {draw, circle, fill=red!20}}`

Comment: `\tikzstyle` is easier to read. Just saying.

Answer (score 78):

TikZ and its underlying engine PGF have a powerful built-in module `pgfkeys`. It can also be used as a standalone package (via `\usepackage{pgfkeys}`) to manipulate options for other purposes.

No matter which command is used, therefore, every defined option goes to some instruction in the form of

```
\pgfkeys{/key family/key/.subkey = {value list} }
```

Since TikZ is the frontend of PGF engine, analogous to LaTeX and TeX, there is a default key family, `tikz`. For example, every `tikzpicture` when started already selects the `tikz` key family and internally the options are processed accordingly if not stated otherwise.

---

As we are mostly using TikZ commands, it is tedious to select the `tikz` key family every time we define a node option etc. so a shortcut serves well here which is the topic of this question. `\tikzset` command is defined as

```
% |\tikzset| is a shortcut to set keys that belongs to the tikz
% family.
\def\tikzset{\pgfqkeys{/tikz}}
```

Hence, `\tikzset` is a wrapper for *Whatever is given next, belongs to the TikZ family*.

---

Up to here, the key family part is handled and we can focus on `key/.subkey` part. There is not much that can be done without refering to the manual on this issue and the `pgfkeys` section is quite comprehensive. I will just emphasize that the most common two examples are `mykey/.code` and `mykey/.style`.

The subkey `/.style` is a collection or a catalogue of options to be processed whenever called for, such as *"define the shape as circle and draw it then run some code and also put a label and fill it with yellow etc."*. A style can also receive some parameters for example, the last example can be achieved by putting

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={draw,circle,label={[fill=yellow]0:#1}}}
\node[mystyle=label text] (nodename) {node text};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

For more wizardry,say with more arguments etc. please refer to the manual. For the sake of convenience, here is another important subkey `/.append style`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={draw,circle,label={[fill=yellow]0:#1}}}
\tikzset{mystyle/.append style={fill=red,rectangle}}
\node[mystyle=label text] (nodename) {node text};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which simply adds the arguments to the key. Note that, `rectangle` comes after `circle` and dominates the previous option, hence, the node becomes a red rectangle. The order of the style specifications matter.

---

Now, back to the question!! We have two options to give style specifications. Namely,

```
\tikzset{mystyle/.style= {draw,circle, etc.} }
\tikzset{mystyle/.append style= {rectangle,fill=red, etc.} }
% or ...
\tikzstyle{mystyle}=[draw,circle,label={[fill=yellow]0:#1}]
\tikzstyle{mystyle}+=[fill=red,rectangle]
```

Both would lead to the same output however as we see that the `\tikzstyle` form is shorter to type in. Other than that, as far as I know there is no particular difference. For example, appending is simply done by putting a `+` sign next to `=` and also as shown below defining a default value is also quite convenient. However `tikzstyle` is only limited to this particular case and it's not applicable to other subkeys e.g. if you want to put a piece of code for some computation you can directly use

```
\tikzset{mystyle/.code={execute whatever is given here}}
```

but there is no `\tikzcode` similar to `\tikzstyle` to achieve this.

Hence, as Altermundus quoted, it's more of a shortcut.

For the interested, below is the code where these commands are defined. The relevant code is given in `tikz.code.tex` file at line 1143.

```
% Styles
\tikzoption{set style}{\tikzstyle#1}

% Handled in a special way.
\def\tikzstyle{\pgfutil@ifnextchar\bgroup\tikz@style@parseA\tikz@style@parseB}
\def\tikz@style@parseB#1={\tikz@style@parseA{#1}=}
\def\tikz@style@parseA#1#2=#3[#4]{% check for an optional argument
  \pgfutil@in@[{#2}%]
  \ifpgfutil@in@%
    \tikz@style@parseC{#1}#2={#4}%
  \else%
    \tikz@style@parseD{#1}#2={#4}%
  \fi%
}%

\def\tikz@style@parseC#1[#2]#3=#4{%
  \pgfkeys{/tikz/#1/.default={#2}}%
  \pgfutil@in@+{#3}%
  \ifpgfutil@in@%
    \pgfkeys{/tikz/#1/.append style={#4}}%
  \else%
    \pgfkeys{/tikz/#1/.style={#4}}%
  \fi}
\def\tikz@style@parseD#1#2=#3{%
  \pgfutil@in@+{#2}%
  \ifpgfutil@in@%
    \pgfkeys{/tikz/#1/.append style={#3}}%
  \else%
    \pgfkeys{/tikz/#1/.style={#3}}%
  \fi}
```

---

At the beginning of the same file there is a note which tells us directly the story about `\tikzoption`:

```
% Note: |\tikzoption| is supported for compatibility only. |\tikzset|
% should be used instead.
```

Comment: Very nice. Maybe add that you can set several keys within the same `\tikzset` command (`\tikzset{my style/.style={...}, my second style/.style={...}, ...}`), which is shorter than using `\tikzstyle` commands. And an added bonus of using `\tikzstyle` is that you can just cut and paste the same list of styles to the options of a `tikzpicture` or a `scope`, which I guess is what Till Tantau means by wanting to "encourage people to keep style settings as local as possible".

Comment: @Jake Thanks. I agree with you but Altermundus pretty much covered these by quoting the man himself :) Feel free to edit anyway. Maybe we should make this CW.

Comment: Pretty long, but the only answer mentioning `+=` being an abbreviation for `.append style` and the fact that many more subkeys don’t have abbreviations in `\tikzstyle`.